Automatically trapping a JSON file from a browser, to use in a VB6 program
I can get the following in Firefox (or any other browser) from a device called a Saturn South ESBox, connected to my local LAN every six seconds, by entering"http://esbox/api/devices".
It's actually a JSON file.
What I don't want to do is sit in front of my PC, doing this once a minute for 24 hours a day, copying this file.
Googling for an answer just doesn't answer the following question (been trying for  months!!)
What can I do to trap this automatically about every minute so I can use it in a Visual Basic 6 program, (then delete it once parsed)?
I'm not worried about parsing it for the info I want - I know exactly what to do, to get that
(about 600 chars of crap removed from the start of the JSON, then four lines similar to the following)
{{"ieee":"001BC502B0102200","status":1,"type":2,"model":"SS9007.2.0_6000_2290_SSHA_R","manuf":"Saturn South","time":{"j":1699407463,"c":1718510500,"r":1718267426,"n":1718510501},"vals":{"cu":15,"en":208630,"po":33,"sw":1,"vo":24029},"ext":{}}
I haven't tried anything, yet, because I don't know how to do this. I wrote a VB6 program years ago using a "Current Cost" device which inputs directly into a PC through USB, but since found out this device was about 20-30% inaccurate through cross modulation. This Esbox from Saturn South has sensors mounted on each phase in the distribution box, is 98% accurate, and detects current flow in both directions, but the transmitter goes through a www source with it's own website. I can access the data through a browser (shown above). I would really love to know how to get this other data, and throw the "Current Cost" device in the bin

You could create another VB6 app (or modify your existing app) that downloads and saves the JSON file using a timer.

I understand very well that I could use a timer in a VB6 program, but what I'm clarifying in my problem is that I don't understand how to get that JSON file by using a program, not by using a browser. I need someone to point me to a program example (in VB6, of course, not .NET or later versions of Visual basic, unless the programs work on both VB6 and the latest Visual Basic). What I would like to make VERY CLEAR is that this if for my own benefit. It's not for marketing, or for sale. So get any idea out of your head that I'm doing this to make a profit.

Here is a simple example of pulling JSON from a URL using a timer.  You will need to set a reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0.
Option Explicit

Private Sub Timer_Timer()
   Dim http As XMLHTTP60
   
   'make the request
   Set http = New XMLHTTP60
   http.Open "GET", "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two"
   http.send

   'now use the json data, or save it to a file,
   'or do whatever else you want with it
   Debug.Print http.responseText
End Sub


Hi Brian - one question -  "Microsoft XML, v6.0" or "MSXML V6.0" is not in 'Project/References" or "Project/Components" so how can I add this reference? I don't have Office 365, just VB6.0, and older separate versions of Windows products

OK, Brian, got something to work, did the http.open, then http.send and then saved http.responseText into a rich text box. BUT, all I got was the contents of the URL site programming, not a .JSON file.  AAuuugghhh!! back to where I was a year ago. Is there something else to add, to extract the JSON file, from the URL site?

If you get JSON by manually typing http://esbox/api/devices, I would have thought it would work with the above approach.  Since I can't test your scenario myself, I don't really have any further insight.

I presume you meant "by manually typing http://esbox/api/devices", you meant into the address bar of a browser, and not into a textbox in a VB program. If so, then, yes, I get a json file shown in the browser's main content area. If I set up a HTTP event in a VB program using that address, I get back the html code of the website, and not the json file. I feel I'm missing something, like a requestheader with contents to do with a json file, but VB responds with "object doesn't support this property or method". Been trawling through SO/other VB sites, but I just can't find the right code. Rats!
